# PostgreSQL in PHP - session variable seems to unset itself when posting data

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to handle a form that updates some data in a postgreSQL table. To do that, I GET the id for the item to update. The URL reads:

`[...]pojazd.php?id=1[...]`, which successfully GETs the data.

Then I want to store it in a session (that was opened before):

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
```

When I use my `$id` variable to SELECT the data, it works fine.

`SELECT model, cena FROM pojazd WHERE id_poj = $id"` does the job.

But when I want to update this data using a POST form:

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])){
[...]
UPDATE pojazd SET model = '$model', cena = '$cena' WHERE id_poj = $id;
}
```

nothing happens. When the `$id` variable is hardcoded (for example: replaced by 1 etc), it works fine. But the `$id` variable seems to unset itself whenever the form is POSTed. I tried echo'ing the `$id` variable whilst disabling the redirecting, and that's exactly what happens - the `$id` variable disappears.

I'm at a loss. The clock is ticking, I really don't want to fail my class, but that problems ruins my entire project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];
```

with

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) $_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];
```

so that the value doesn't get overwritten with an empty value when the form is `POST`ed...

Comment: Such a stupid mistake... I panicked and stopped thinking logically. Thank you <3